# Optimizer does not optimize any variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I would like to solve my optimization problem but the optimizer does not work. I expect an array of solutions with minimum difference to the given value, but my calculated softmax function is 1 all the time, because the weights and biases are not updated in the iterations. They are both tensors of zeros. How can I fix this problem?

```
#KI-Model
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 5], name='input') #x_1-x_5


#Init
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5,1]), dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), dtype=tf.float32)

#Sigmoid
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b) 

#Training
y_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name='output')

loss = y-y_tensor
cost = tf.square(loss)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.003).minimize(cost)


#Start
session = tf.Session() 
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
session.run(init)


#init first 1000 training_batches
for i in range(1000):
    batch_xs.append([dataA[i], dataB[i], dataC[i], dataD[i],
              dataE[i]])
    batch_ys.append([solution[i]])

for i in range(10000):

    session.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x:batch_xs, y_tensor:batch_ys})

print(session.run(y, feed_dict={x:batch_xs, y_tensor:batch_ys}) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't compute and applied the gradients.
These lines have been missing:

```
gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss=cost)
train_step = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars=gradients)
```

You also need to run the train step on each iteration, with this line:

```
session.run(train_step, feed_dict={x:batch_xs, y_tensor:batch_ys})
```

The full correct code:

```
#KI-Model
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 5], name='input') #x_1-x_5


#Init
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([5,1]), dtype=tf.float32)
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]), dtype=tf.float32)

#Sigmoid
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

#Training
y_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name='output')

loss = y-y_tensor
cost = tf.square(loss)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.003)
gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(loss=cost)
train_step = optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars=gradients)

#Start
session = tf.Session()
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
session.run(init)


#init first 1000 training_batches
for i in range(1000):
    batch_xs.append([dataA[i], dataB[i], dataC[i], dataD[i],
              dataE[i]])
    batch_ys.append([solution[i]])

for i in range(10000):

    session.run(train_step, feed_dict={x:batch_xs, y_tensor:batch_ys})

print(session.run(y, feed_dict={x:batch_xs, y_tensor:batch_ys}) )
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, Matan. The effect is the same. The calculated funktion is always 1 and the biases and weights were not updated. The problem I see at the moment is the following: My input values are far away from 1 and my output values are also far away from 1. The calculated function is a linear combination of sigmoid functions. Theses functions which reaches it's maximum at 1. This causes that the liear combination of multiple sigmoid functions has the maximum at 1, too. So my y can not go over 1, but it is the best fitting value for the regression. Seems to be a math problem